# Migrating from SVN to Git with SVN repository having no trunk tags, and branches

Tags: git, svn

I am trying to migrate my SVN repository to Git keeping all the history intact. My SVN repository has a non standard layout and the project files are directly under the repository root. There are no tags and branches.

I firstly used `git svn clone` to migrate the repo. the command completed successfully but when I did `git branch -r` I did not get anything.

Next I used `svn2git`. I firstly tried to use it with `--rootistrunk` option but the command did not run and I couldn't see anything in the console. I read somewhere that `--rootistrunk` has some issues and to use
`svn2git <svn-url> trunk / --no-minimize-url --verbose`. The command ran but it failed at the last with the error message:

> svn2git error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to
> git. command failed: git checkout -f master.

Can anyone suggest how I can get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For a non-standard SVN layout, try a [`subgit import`](http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html#7)

[SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/) is more robust than `git svn` (and has free version for a one-time dvn to Git import)

Comment: Thanks VonC I will give that a try. In the meanwhile there is another issue that i am stuck with. I am trying to do a git svn clone of a very large SVN repo. I have done earlier migrations using git svn clone with full branching, tags, and history maintained and all have gone well. But this time the script after running for quite some time throws an error: libsvn: Out of memory - terminating application.18 [main] perl 13884 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to perl.exe.stackdumpIf somebody has encountered similar error I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: @Anshul Strange: best to ask a new question in that case.